# "Realm accessed from incorrect thread" while having a separate instance of Realm in the operation block

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am updating a realm object in a separate background operation and creating the Realm instance in the operation block itself but still getting this error. Any clues?

```
- (void)didFavoriteButtonTapped:(FlickerPhotoCell *)photoCell {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:photoCell];
FlickerPhoto *photo = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
photoCell.photoFavouriteButton.selected = !photo.isFavorited;

[self.opQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    photo.isFavorited = !photo.isFavorited;
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    //Saving in local database
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoURL == %@ AND isFavorited == YES", photo.photoURL];
    RLMResults *searchedPhotos = [FlickerPhoto objectsWithPredicate:pred];
    FlickerPhoto *photoInDatabase = [searchedPhotos firstObject];
    BOOL isPhotoExists = (photoInDatabase != nil);

    if(photo.isFavorited) {
        if(!isPhotoExists) {
            [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
                [realm addObject:photo];
            }];
        }
    } else {
        if(isPhotoExists) {
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            [realm deleteObject:photoInDatabase];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        }
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Realm is not Tread safe. So Whenever you would like to write to Realm it has to be on the same Thread that you created the object.
So before you start the "addOperationWithBlock" operation, you should get the unique identifier of the object you are trying to access, and then create it from the within the operation block.

So you can do one of three options:

1. update the realm object on the same thread, by the way, from my experience it's some times good enough,  realm write transaction is't a very expensive task. But again it depends how often this is called.
2. Create the object again, in the new thread, and pass a unique identifier, instead of the realm object itself, and re create it on the thread you are going to write to:

   ```
   - (void)didFavoriteButtonTapped:(FlickerPhotoCell *)photoCell {


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:photoCell];
       FlickerPhoto *photo = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
       NSString *photoUniqueIdentifier = photo.id // Getting I'ts identifier before opening a new thread 
       photoCell.photoFavouriteButton.selected = !photo.isFavorited;

       [self.opQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

       FlickerPhoto *photoToUpdate = [FlickerPhoto objectForPrimaryKey:photoUniqueIdentifier]; // Getting the object again from the data base, in the new thread contex

       RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
       [realm beginWriteTransaction];
       photoToUpdate.isFavorited = !photoToUpdate.isFavorited;
       [realm commitWriteTransaction];

       //Saving in local database
       NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoURL == %@ AND isFavorited == YES", photoToUpdate.photoURL];
       RLMResults *searchedPhotos = [FlickerPhoto objectsWithPredicate:pred];
       FlickerPhoto *photoInDatabase = [searchedPhotos firstObject];
       BOOL isPhotoExists = (photoInDatabase != nil);

       if(photoToUpdate.isFavorited) {
           if(!isPhotoExists) {
               [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
                   [realm addObject:photoToUpdate];
               }];
           }
       } else {
           if(isPhotoExists) {
               [realm beginWriteTransaction];
               [realm deleteObject:photoInDatabase];
               [realm commitWriteTransaction];
           }
       }
   }];
   ```

   }
3. Or you can create it with alloc init, and set I'ts unique identifier by hand (not it a write transaction) and then you can access it from any thread, because I'ts not an data base object yet.